# Instead of library name display view name

Tags: sharepoint-online

In the image below, is it possible to show view name instead of library name where I've written?

I know how to hide this one using script but trying to see if I can help out user. We have 20 views in single library. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to revert the list experience back to classic thereby enabling the view selector menu directly below the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However, what I wanted to do is, where the 'Documents' is show above, I want to put list name. I suppose this is hard to do inside a library?

Comment: Hey Dingo.  My suggestion was a workaround.  In classic experience, the view name is more prominently displayed, and may make it easier for some of your users to access the 20+ views.  

Another workaround suggestion would be to add the library to a web page.  You can edit the web part title to be the view name that you set as the web part’s default view.  Additionally, if the users need to be able to access the 20+ views, you can enable the view selector menu in the web part’s Miscellaneous section by deselecting Disable view selector menu.